# Paypal plans: monthly (OK), yearly (OK) and lifetime (is that even possible?)

Tags: paypal

Sorry for the weird format of my title, I hope it accurately explains my problem. I'm trying to create 3 subscription plans: Monthly, Yearly and Lifetime.

I was able to create the Monthly and Yearly plans on but I can't figure out how to add a lifetime plan (aka a one-time payment that grants the subscription forever).

The only workaround I could think of is to simply use Monthly and Yearly for recurring payment and to create a different product for the lifetime plan, but that bothers me a little that I have to add the extra logic in my code to check if the client has bought the lifetime subscription product. Is there another way that would make it so the lifetime subscription would be the same product ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only workaround I could think of is to simply use Monthly and Yearly for recurring payment and to create a ***different product*** for the lifetime plan,

That is exactly how you do it.

> Is there another way that would make it so the lifetime subscription would be the same product ?

No.  What you describe above is precisely how it is done.

> but that bothers me a little that I have to add the extra logic in my code to check if the client has bought the lifetime subscription product.

I don't mean to bring you bad news but if you are "bothered" by that - I might suggest dropping the project.

Unfortunately you will find that there is a ***truly incredible*** amount of work to do, to achieve subscriptions and purchases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using this workaround doesn't bother me because of the amount of work (which is not much really) but because it affects the coherence and consistensy of the data in my system. If I have 200 products and each of them have monthly, yearly and lifetime plans, all of a sudden I have 400 products and an extra column in my database to say that this product is in fact the same as that other one because I want to be able to offer people to upgrade their subscription and to prevent them from paying for a plan when they already have the lifetime subscription for that product.

Comment: I get you on coherence for sure - it's a good point.  Sadly, that's the deal though!

Answer (score 1):

> how to add a lifetime plan  (aka a one-time payment that grants the subscription forever).

You can call it a lifetime subscription as a business matter, but this is not a "subscription" as far as PayPal processing is concerned: one-time payments are not processed via PayPal Subscriptions.

You need a regular integration of PayPal Checkout ([demo](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server)) for something that involves a one-time payment.